# jQuery - Ajax select option Drupal Custom Form 'POST Error 500'

Tags: jquery, ajax, drupal, drupal-forms

`enter code here`How to update a select option based on other select option value selected.

POST `http://localhost/drupal_site/form_elements` 500 (Internal Server Error) jquery.min.js:19
o.extend.ajax jquery.min.js:19
(anonymous function) form_elements.js:17  --> `jQuery.ajax({`
o.event.handle jquery.min.js:19
o.event.add.J

the jquery code is:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    jQuery("#edit-deptopsgt").change(function(){

        if($(this).val()!=""){
            var dato=$(this).val();

             jQuery.ajax({
                type:"POST",
                dataType:"html",
                url:"#",
                data:"id_depto="+dato+"&tarea=listProvincia", success:function(msg){
                    $("#edit-municipio").empty().removeAttr("disabled").append(msg);
                }
             });
        } 
        else {
            //$("#edit-municipio").empty().attr("disabled","disabled");
            //$("#ciudad").empty().attr("disabled","disabled");
        }

    }); 

});
```

Comment: You have a server-side error, not client-side.

Comment: As @KevinB mentioned, a 500 error indicates an issue on the server side, not in the client side javascript/jquery

Comment: thanks the error now is just: POST http://localhost/drupal_site/form_elements  jquery.min.js:19
o.extend.ajax jquery.min.js:19
(anonymous function) form_elements.js:17  (In Line 17: jQuery.ajax({)
o.event.handle jquery.min.js:19
o.event.add.J jquery.min.js:19

Answer (score 0):

In your ajax callback why url : '#' ?

if you want to use ajax call back, then  you must specify a valid url. Otherwise use simple jquery click event instead of ajax call back.

**Example AJAX Callback :**

```
$.ajax({
                url: '/my_callback.php',
                type: 'post',
                dataType: 'json',
                data: {'email':'test@test.com'},
                    complete: function(response) {
                        resObj = $.parseJSON(response.responseText);
                        if(resObj.status == 'success') {
                           alert('Valid Email')
                        }
                        else {
                           alert('Invalid Email');
                        }
                    }
});
```

Thanks and regards

ARUN AK